# HTML special character

Tags: html

I need some help, i entered a special character in form like **"ä"** and it was save in a database, but when I call it using a javascript , a suggestion type, it does not display correctly, it display like this **"Ã¤"**.

Is it possible from the form **"ä"** it will be save as **"&auml"** in the database? how is it?

Comment: Show us the code you used.

Comment: You don't want it to save as `&auml` in your database.  Always use the right encoding at the right level.  If you need to send your information out to a printer, or email, then the HTML encoding will *not* be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by misinterpreting a [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) string as [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1).  The character "ä" is represented in UTF-8 by the two bytes 0xC3 0xA4, but in ISO-8859-1, the byte 0xC3 represents the character "Ã", and the byte 0xA4 represents the character "¤".

Most likely, your program is sending the page as UTF-8 but not telling the browser what encoding was used, so the browser is assuming ISO-8859-1 (the default).  You need to send a `Content-Type` HTTP header that specifies the encoding, such as `text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you should define the character set used by your page.

Add this inside your `<head>` tags:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

There are [other character sets](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472651) as well, but UTF-8, as [stated](http://googleblog.blogspot.fr/2008/05/moving-to-unicode-51.html) by Google back in 2008, has become one of the most popular today.

Comment: Is it possible from the form "ä" it will be save as "&auml" in the database? how is it?

Comment: @user3928061 Yes, it is. If you could kindly edit your question to include some of your code, we could take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your character set, but there are two character sets that you need to keep in mind. The first is the character set in the database, and the second is the character set in your HTML. They need to match.

Even if you do something like `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` in your connection script, the database needs to have utf8 also for the data to display properly.